# Spark 'join' DataFrame with List and return String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame:

```
DF1:
+------+---------+
|key1  |Value    |
+------+---------+
|[k, l]|      1  |
|[m, n]|      2  |
|[o]   |      3  |
+------+---------+
```

that needs to be 'joined' with another dataframe

```
DF2:
+----+
|key2|
+----+
|k   |
|l   |
|m   |
|n   |
|o   |
+----+
```

so that the output looks like this:

```
DF3:
+--------------------+---------+
|key3                |Value    |
+--------------------+---------+
|k:1 l:1 m:0 n:0 o:0 |      1  |
|k:0 l:0 m:1 n:1 o:0 |      2  |
|k:0 l:0 m:0 n:0 o:1 |      3  |
+--------------------+---------+
```

In other words, the output dataframe should have a column that is a string of all rows in DF2, and each element should be followed by a 1 or 0 indicating whether that element was present in the list in the column key1 of DF1.

I am not sure how to go about it. Is there a simple UDF I can write to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For operation like this to be possible `DF2` so you can just use `udf`:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = Seq(
  (Seq("k", "l"), 1), (Seq("m", "n"), 2), (Seq("o"), 3)
).toDF("key1", "value")
val df2 = Seq("k", "l", "m", "n", "o").toDF("key2")

val keys = df2.as[String].collect.map((_, 0)).toMap

val toKeyMap = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => 
   xs.foldLeft(keys)((acc, x) => acc + (x -> 1)))


df1.select(toKeyMap($"key1").alias("key3"), $"value").show(false)

// +-------------------------------------------+-----+
// |key3                                       |value|
// +-------------------------------------------+-----+
// |Map(n -> 0, m -> 0, l -> 1, k -> 1, o -> 0)|1    |
// |Map(n -> 1, m -> 1, l -> 0, k -> 0, o -> 0)|2    |
// |Map(n -> 0, m -> 0, l -> 0, k -> 0, o -> 1)|3    |
// +-------------------------------------------+-----+
```

If you want just a string:

```
val toKeyMapString = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => 
   xs.foldLeft(keys)((acc, x) => acc + (x -> 1))
     .map { case (k, v) => s"$k: $v" }
     .mkString(" ")
)


df1.select(toKeyMapString($"key1").alias("key3"), $"value").show(false)
// +------------------------+-----+
// |key3                    |value|
// +------------------------+-----+
// |n: 0 m: 0 l: 1 k: 1 o: 0|1    |
// |n: 1 m: 1 l: 0 k: 0 o: 0|2    |
// |n: 0 m: 0 l: 0 k: 0 o: 1|3    |
// +------------------------+-----+
```